# How to display health using GUIText?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to display my health as the GUIText and decreasing when the player hits. How to code based on my health script?

Here is my healthscript

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour {

     public static HealthScript instance;
     public int hp = 1;
     private GUIText scoreReference;
     private GUIText highscoreReference;
     private static int _highscore = -1;
     public int highscore { 
         get { if (_highscore == -1) 
             _highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore", 0);
             return _highscore; 
         }
         set {
             if (value > _highscore) {
                 _highscore = value;
                 highscoreReference.text = _highscore.ToString();
                 PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", _highscore);
             }
         }
     }

     public bool isEnemy = true;


     private static int points;
     public void Damage(int damageCount) {
         hp -= damageCount;

         if (hp <= 0)
         {
             // Dead!
             Destroy(gameObject);
             points++;
             scoreReference.text = points.ToString();
         }
     }

     public void gameEnd() {

         highscore = points;
         points = 0;
     }


     void Start()
     {
         scoreReference = GameObject.Find("Score").guiText;
         highscoreReference = GameObject.Find("HighScore").guiText;
         scoreReference.text = points.ToString(); 
         highscoreReference.text = highscore.ToString ();
         instance = this;
     }
```

UPDATE: I DON'T WANT TO DISPLAY ENEMY HEALTH, THIS SCRIPT WAS ATTACHED TO EVERY ENEMY

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use OnGui method always to show the interface of the game

```
void OnGUI(){
    GUI.color = Color.red;
    GUI.Label(new Rect (20,20,200,20), "Health = " + hp);
}
```

All the documentation you need to understand this code is here:

GUI.Label http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html
OnGui method: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html

Hope this help you, ask if you have any troubles with this code!

Comment: The OnGui method runs every frame, and it´s used to represent the interface of the game.
With GUI.Label you are creating a "box" with Rect´s size and the text "Health" + your hp variable.

Just paste the code (I´ve just edited the code, had a bug) and run the game, you´ll see how it works ;)

Comment: alright, i'm added that code, but it wasn't display, something missing?

Comment: Sorry, my answer got an error, now I´ve tested and works perfect. The solution is edited so now you can test it :)

Comment: i was tried to created a new scene, and then implement that ONLY code, yeah nothing happen. Should i create a new object and implement that code?

Comment: It´s always good to create empty gameObject called gameController and then attach all the scripts you need to run on the game to that gameobject.

Comment: that's the convinient way i think, i will try that on my next project.

Comment: hey sorry for asking again, that healthscript actually for enemy and player, and the problem is, it's show both player and enemy health, how should i do? @Carlos Navas

Comment: I don´t understand your question, if you want to display enemy and player´s health, the only thing you have to do is to attach the script to enemy´s Gameobject and change the position of the Rect in the screen. If you don´t change the Rect position, both text will overlap. Sorry about my English

Comment: that's the problem @Carlos Navas, it's overlap. It's show 2 health..enemy and player. I don't the enemy. The healthscript use by 2 gameobject, enemy and player. Do you have a solution? i'm trying to make if else statement in the OnGUI method. I think it's wrong..

just something like this..

if (GameObject.Find("Player"));
      {
  GUI.Label(new Rect (5,300,100,100), "Health =" + hp);

Comment: Ok, you can solve this "problem" easy way. Just create a public boolean variable (public bool isPlayer;). Now, in your GameObject inspector you can select the value of the variable (true if you are in player´s gameObject, false if you are in enemy´s gameObject).

And then, create an if else statement with isPlayer. You should have no problem with this, don´t hesitate to help and vote up if it works!

Comment: hey @Carlos Navas, do you mind to email me? got some question, i don't want to extend this post with the other question. Do contact me at brutalpanda05@gmail.com thanks! :)

Comment: You can post another question, I always check unity3d section ;)

Comment: I can't post a question right now, haha. i've reached my limit to post question, that's the reason @Carlos Navas

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable to show on the GUI with C# easily by doing:

```
var myNiceVariable = "Showing the health values!";
var guiText = GameObject.Find("GUI Text").GetComponent(GUIText);
guiText.text = myNiceVariable;
```

Or you can use the [OnGui](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) method, you can add to your script:

```
void OnGui(){
     GUI.Label(new Rect (5,5,10,100), "Health: " + hp);
}
```

Code taken from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/62548/how-can-i-display-a-variable-as-a-guitext.html) and [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/402506/display-variables-in-guitext.html).

Comment: do you mean something like this?



void OnGui()
 {
  GUILayout.Label(Rect (5,5,10,100), "Points : " +hp);
 }

Comment: Yep, I'm updating the answer to show it in C#. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: im added that line of code, but it said UnityEngine.Rect is a type but it use like variable

Comment: Check the update, the "new" keyboard was missing. You can create the Rect outside the code and use it there as well.